# Using ng-repeat and filter, how to tell which items are visible?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects that I'm displaying in my Angular app using `ng-repeat`. I'm filtering out items using `filter` and the value of a search input. It works as expected. But, I have a "select all" / "deselect all" option and I only want to select the *visibile* items in the list (the ones that meet the current search criteria).

Without performing the same logic in my controller (i.e. using `indexOf` the search value on each of my objects), how can I tell which items are currently filtered out by `ng-repeat`/`filter`?

My view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchValue">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkAll" ng-change="toggleAll()">

<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:searchValue">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

A function in my controller:

```
$scope.toggleAll() {
     for(var i in $scope.items){
         // how can I tell if this item is filtered out in the view?
     }
}
```

I have significantly simplified my code samples here for simplicity since this question doesn't need much more detail. Is there a way to do what I'm thinking or do I need to perform the "search" again?

Comment: Check out @azium 's comment on my answer. You'll probably want to use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Comment: Of course, I was just throwing it out there as a quick example! Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can bind the filtered array to another scope variable in your view, then access that in your controller.

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter:searchValue)">
  ...
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function () {
  angular.forEach($scope.filteredItems, function (item) {
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

Comment: I've never seen this feature before, it's awesome! Do you know when they added it?

Comment: I don't, but I have some 1.27 code that uses it.. so it's been out for a while.

Comment: This is awesome - exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: works great, unfortunately it is not supported by angular utils dir-paginate incase anyone else stumbles across this and has the same issues

Comment: @pcnate do you have any solutions for dir-paginate?

Comment: I don't have access to the code today, but I basically left the dir paginate alone. I added something similar to this where I wanted access to the same items `{{ ( vm.myItems | filter1 | filter2 | sorting | dirPaginationPageFilter ).length }}` to get the number of items in my view. For in the controller it was a bit more complicated but I used nested `$filters` to do the same thing. I'll post an answer on Monday giving more details about what I did for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that ng-repeat is scope isolated. As a result you can't refer to the internal list that is being managed by ng-repeat from your controller/directive.

As a result there are 2 options

1. Bind the filtered list to ng-repeat from your controller/directive, so you    maintain the filtered list.

   ```
   //in your controller
   $scope.filteredItems = $filter('yourFilter')($scope.items,$scope.searchText);
   $scope.$watch('searchText', function(newValue){
      $scope.filteredItems = $filter('yourFilter')($scope.items, newValue);
   });

   //in your view
   <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">
       <td>{{item.id}}</td>
       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. Perform the filter again in your controller/directive

   ```
   $scope.toggleAll() {
       var items = $filter('yourFilter')($scope.items, $scope.searchText);
       for(var i in items){
          //set your selected property
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Angular filters create [a new array.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) So in order to perform an action on the filtered items you're going to have to capture the new array.

Something like:

```
$scope.toggleAll() {
  var filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, $scope.searchValue);
  for(var i in filteredItems) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you don't want to filter twice you'll have to filter the array yourself every time `searchValue` changes and `ng-repeat` over that filtered array, [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) is useful in that case.

Comment: Don't use `for..in` for arrays! It doesn't do what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Comment: @azium right you are. I simply copy and pasted the OP's snippet.

Comment: Oh woops. it's the end of the day, I swear! Thanks for notifying OP =D