# Accessing ng-repeat alias expression in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have a filtered list, within a directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:filter | limitTo:5 as filteredItems">
    <div ng-bind="item.title"></div>
</div>
<div><span ng-bind="filteredItems.length"></span> items</div>
```

I wish to access and manipulate the filtered list in the directive's controller. However `scope.filteredItems` is `undefined` in the controller.

How can I pass the filtered array to the directive's controller?

Comment: check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718300/using-ng-repeat-and-filter-how-to-tell-which-items-are-visible/30718588#30718588

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Was my suggestion able to help you?

Comment: @salniro the issue is on hold while we work on some other stuff... will probably pick it up again next week.

Comment: @Adamski any progress on this? Could you check out my suggestion and see if it works? You can always check out the fiddle then implement this in your specific scenario when you find convenient. I would like to see this question get resolved

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to get a hold of your filtered array by injecting `$filter` into your controller and leveraging the following, targeting your custom filter of `filter`

```
$scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items)
```

This will include your new array with both filters of `filter` and `limitTo` applied. Observe the simplistic example to demonstrate this

```
<span ng-bind="filteredItems.length"></span><!-- 2 -->
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter | limitTo: 2 as filteredItems"></div>
```

---

```
app.filter('filter', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.slice(0, 4); // 4 items - initial filter
   };
})

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.items = [
        {'key': 'A', 'value': 0},
        {'key': 'B', 'value': 1},
        {'key': 'C', 'value': 2},
        {'key': 'D', 'value': 3},
        {'key': 'E', 'value': 4},
        {'key': 'F', 'value': 5},
        {'key': 'G', 'value': 6},
        {'key': 'H', 'value': 7}
    ];

    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items) // 2 items - compound filter
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3ksw0uwd/) - working example